# Making a staircase using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ascii-art

Here is my answer to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44745975/6517383), which I think is quite inefficient considering its length:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
 function makeEqual(blocks,dash) {
  var n =blocks;
  var widthSize = dash *10;
  var i=0;
  var equal = "";
  var contentName = "";
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
 
  if(i==(n-1)) {
   contentName='contentL'+i;
  equal = "<div id="+contentName+">"+produceDashStructure(dash*3)+"</div>"; 
  $("#main").append(equal);
  $("#"+contentName).css({marginLeft:i*widthSize , width:widthSize*3});
   for(j=i;j>0;j--) {
     contentName='contentR'+j;
      equal = "<div id="+contentName+">"+produceDashStructure(dash)+"</div>"; 
      $("#main").append(equal);
      $("#"+contentName).css({marginLeft:((n-j)+i+2)*widthSize , width:widthSize , bottom: (((n-j)*2))*55 , position: "relative" });
    }
  }
   else {
    contentName='contentL'+i;
      equal = "<div id="+contentName+">"+produceDashStructure(dash)+"</div>"; 
      $("#main").append(equal);
  $("#"+contentName).css({marginLeft:i*widthSize , width:widthSize});
    }
  }
  
  }
  function produceDashStructure(dash) {    
      var dashedStructure = "";
    for(var i=0;i<dash;i++) {
         dashedStructure += "- "; 
      }
       return dashedStructure+"<br/><br/>"+dashedStructure;
  }

  makeEqual(5,5);
})
```

```css
#main {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 30 px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    
</div>
```

I have written a lot of code for a small problem which I think is time-inefficient too, and I'm using the same methodology in my projects. Any improvement in this question will help me make all my projects more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to comment when the original question was very vague, the Original-OP (O-OP) failed to answer questions, different interpretations were made by the various respondants, and there's (currently) no accepted answer. Even worse, someone saw fit to remove the `jQuery` tag, implying that only a CSS solution would suffice - a view that did not come from the O-OP.

None of that was your fault.

The worst feature of this answer (and possibly others) is that the paradigm is reliant on a particular font size - change it and the step-formation falls apart.

You might consider something like the version below, which goes a long was to fixing that particular issue, and tidies up the code considerably :

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    function makeEqual($container, dashes, n) {
        var $step, scale = {}, i;

        // Create a single step and proactively measure its width and height in the target container.
        // IIFE allows working member `dashString` to be GC'd. 
        (function(dashString) {
            $step = $("<div/>").html(dashString + "<br/><br/>" + dashString).css({'position': 'absolute', 'width': 'auto', 'white-space': 'nowrap'}).appendTo($container);
            scale.w = $step.width();
            scale.h = $step.height();
            $step.remove();
        })(Array.apply(null, new Array(dashes)).map(function() {return '- '}).join('')); // pass in the required string of dashes and spaces

        // create staircases - descending and ascending in the same loop
        for(i=0; i<(n-1); i++) {
            $step.clone().css({ 'left': i * scale.w, 'top': i * scale.h }).appendTo($container); // descending steps
            $step.clone().css({ 'left': (2 * n - i) * scale.w, 'top': i * scale.h }).appendTo($container); // ascending steps
        }
        // create bridge-piece
        for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
            $step.clone().css({ 'left': (n - 1 + i) * scale.w, 'top': (n - 1) * scale.h }).appendTo($container); // bridge-piece
        }
    }
    makeEqual($("#main").empty(), 5, 3);
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yt0za9xp/3/)**

Notes :

1. no ids and no rediscovery of freshly appended DOM elements.
2. no need for the `dashStructure()` function - instead, positioned clones of the prototype `$step` are appended.
3. all steps are absolutely positioned on the same bases using `left` and `top`; the vagaries of mixed natural flow and relative positioning are avoided.
4. the number of assignments is greatly reduced.
5. consistent indentation!!